# MVVM: Dealing with Very Large View Models

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a working View-Model with several hundred properties, each actively consumed by one or more client views. This technically serves its purpose as a traffic director, but my concern is that legacy maintenance will be a nightmare. I've tried splitting this up into multiple extra classes and then running singleton for each one inside of the VM, but that leaves the front-end dev scratching his head as to what instance object will lead to any given target property. I've tried dividing the VM into partial class files. This works particularly well for command implementation, but for properties this is not realistic(there would be hundreds, or even thousands of code files for the VM alone), and going this direction just leaves me too reliant on the F12 key(jump to definition). Has anyone else encountered this problem using MVVM(or even MVC)? I need a way to manage these property definitions without the aid of a rebreather!

Comment: Generally with MVVM, there is one view model per view. It sounds like you are supporting a number of views with a single view model. Could that be the reason your view model has so many properties, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm using machine-state to manage my views. This UI in particular has about 20 views, all reading from the same data source. It only seemed natural to me that they should all share the same VM. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

Comment: Your question is probably better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: noted. i may be in the wrong place for problems concerning architecture.

Comment: One view model to rule them all?  Usually classes have single responsibilities and are composed to construct an application.  Target properties are found in their logical place within the object graph, not just artificially slammed into the root.

Comment: I'm not using a God object. I have a fully flushed out data-tier, multiple component libraries on the front end, and the BLL responsibilities are divided among multiple intermediary custom types. In my design pattern, the VM serves merely as traffic director. It just so happens there is quite a bit of traffic..

Answer (score 3):

Typically you would have one ViewModel class per View. A view could be a Window, UserControl or Page. It is possible to have one ViewModel serve as the DataContext for your entire application, but the thought horrifies me.
You could have each view resolve its own ViewModel instance.

It is difficult to advise without seeing the source code and architecture of your application

Comment: I never considered having a different VM for each and every component of the application. How would I update the DataContext of View A from View B?

Comment: It depends on how they are related. You might be best using a publish-subscribe type messaging system like Prism's EventAggregator.

Comment: The advantages of having a shared DataContext object accoss multiple views are too great.There must be a happy medium somewhere in between. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: In software development there are no advantages bigger than maintainability and testability and those 2 are greatly improved by breaking your code up into smaller, more manageable pieces.

Comment: Which is the greatest strength of dividing a solitary view into multiple ones, each sharing the same data-binding. I am at liberty to slice the UI into as many segments as needed without the mandate of creating another VM for every single one. I can even swap in and swap out components on a whim, and none need even have knowledge of what they are, only that they are bound to some property of my discretion. Testability is a given. Not to mention the ICommand model is portable across every view. I can call the same command from customer view as the freight view. There is immense power here.

Comment: The only threat to maintainability is how to organize the code files. And I hardly see that as a mandate to steamroll the entire architecture. It just means I have some remodeling to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought each View would have its own ViewModel that updates the underlying Model AND/OR Observes changes to the underlying model. The Model being a Domain Object. The Domain Object being the core of the architecture which abstracts all of the extremities (DB, Services, etc). If some property of the Model changes Value, all ViewModels observing the change would be updated of the change when the Model notifies of the change (e.g., after persistence succeeds).